# How to make Dependency Injection work for a Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which I am trying to inject a repository. Every time I try to use the repository its null. Here is a snippet of code:

My main application

```
package com.cisco.ido.no2.deployment;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class No2AlDeviceDeploymentIdApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(No2AlDeviceDeploymentIdApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My component

```
@Component
@PostBack(route = "no2.deployment", dataClass = String.class, queue = "no2-deployment")
public class DevicePostbackRunnable extends PostBackRunnable<String> {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceTypeRepository deviceTypeRepository;

    public DevicePostbackRunnable() {}

    public DevicePostbackRunnable(Class<String> dataClass) {
        super(dataClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void processTaskResult(String result, RunningTask runningTask) {
        DeviceType dt = deviceTypeRepository.findOne((long)12);  // <-----here
        int yy = 90;
    }
}
```

Here is my repository code:

```
package com.cisco.ido.no2.deployment.repositories;

import com.cisco.ido.no2.deployment.entities.DeviceType;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DeviceTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<DeviceType, Long> {

}
```

My package name for DevicePostBackRunnable is `com.cisco.ido.no2.deployment`. When I call `DeviceType dt = deviceTypeRepository.findOne` it is always null. Is there a way to make this work? Also, when I inject this repository in my Rest Controller it works fine.

Comment: could you post your `spring-boot main application` with package name?

Comment: @andolsizied Hi ive posted my main application

Comment: could you post `DevicePostbackRunnable` package name?

Comment: I think you have a problem in your code's structure, see this linke : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Comment: can you show us how you are defining DeviceTypeRepository bean? Also how come no component-scan? lastly what is the postBack annotation?

Comment: who's creating `DevicePostBackRunnable`?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll `DevicePostBackRunnable` is created using reflection in one of our external libraries.

Comment: @dimitrisli I tried component-scan but it still didnt work. I posted the DeviceTypeRepository code.

Comment: What if you add the @Repository annotation on that DeviceTypeRepository defintion?

Comment: @dimitrisli I added it but still no luck

Comment: @Luke101 could you post where `DevicePostbackRunnable` is used and how it's created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put @Repository in your interface **DeviceTypeRepository**. So that 
the class will automatically be detected by the Spring container as part of the container's component scanning process when you used @Autowired.

From Spring Documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations

> The @Repository annotation is a marker for any class that fulfills the
>   role or stereotype of a repository (also known as Data Access Object
>   or DAO). Among the uses of this marker is the automatic translation of
>   exceptions as described in Section 20.2.2, “Exception translation”.
>
> Spring provides further stereotype annotations: @Component, @Service,
>   and @Controller. @Component is a generic stereotype for any
>   Spring-managed component. @Repository, @Service, and @Controller are
>   specializations of @Component for more specific use cases, for
>   example, in the persistence, service, and presentation layers,
>   respectively. Therefore, you can annotate your component classes with
>   @Component, but by annotating them with @Repository, @Service, or
>   @Controller instead, your classes are more properly suited for
>   processing by tools or associating with aspects. For example, these
>   stereotype annotations make ideal targets for pointcuts. It is also
>   possible that @Repository, @Service, and @Controller may carry
>   additional semantics in future releases of the Spring Framework. Thus,
>   if you are choosing between using @Component or @Service for your
>   service layer, @Service is clearly the better choice. Similarly, as
>   stated above, @Repository is already supported as a marker for
>   automatic exception translation in your persistence layer.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface should have one of the following annotations in order to be injectable by spring:

```
@Component
@Service
@Repository
@Controller
```